# Azure notification hub installantion

Tags: azure, installation

Fast question. How create installation using templates? Can you give an example? How construct 'InstallationTemplate' object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to create an ARM template based on the json schema of [Microsoft.NotificationHubs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-04-01/Microsoft.NotificationHubs.json):

- Create a new project in Visual Studio 2015.
- Choose for a Cloud project
- Choose for Azure Resource Group
- Choose Blank Template
- Open azuredeploy.json

You will see this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
    },
    "variables": {
    },
    "resources": [
    ],
    "outputs": {
    }
}
```

Then begin with the resources part by typing apiVersion (note that you get intellisense already):

```
"resources": [
    {
       "apiVersion": ""
    }
  ],
```

After this add the type: Just select the correct value.
After the type is set. You will get intellisense on the allowed properties.
There are more parameters available. But when using the main properties and 
create parameters of the hardcoded values and at the end you will get a template like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "namespaceLocation": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "namespaceName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "notificationHubName": {
        "type": "string"
      }
  },
    "variables": {
    },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
      "name": "[parameters('namespaceName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces",
      "location": "[parameters('namespaceLocation')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('namespaceName')]",
        "namespaceType": "NotificationHub"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2014-09-01",
          "name": "[parameters('notificationHubName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationHubs",
          "location": "[parameters('namespaceLocation')]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/', parameters('namespaceName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('notificationHubName')]"           
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
    "outputs": {
    }
}
```